# wrap wysiwyg editor's iframe

Tags: jquery, sceditor

I'm using sceditor in one my projects, and I need to wrap the `iframe` with a `div`. However, when I do that, the content gets erased and of course I don't know why.

Can someone throw some light on why is this happening?

To test this, just go http://www.sceditor.com/ and with firebug execute this in the console

```
$(".sceditor-container iframe").wrap("<div class='some_class'></div>");
```

I've also tried to alter the source code with no luck.

Answer (score -1):

SCE's CSS and js requires that everything is placed in the correct place.
Why do you need such thing?

Comment: Actually, this is what I'm after: [http://stackoverflow.com/q/32142462/702353](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32142462/702353)